# Re-scaling outputs from a Keras model back to original scale

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, normalization

I'm new to neural nets (just a disclaimer).

I have a regression problem of predicting the strength of concrete, based on 8 features. What I've done first, is rescaled the data using min-max normalization:

```
# Normalize data between 0 and 1
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

min_max = MinMaxScaler()
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(min_max.fit_transform(dataframe), columns = dataframe.columns)
```

then converted the dataframe into numpy array and split it into X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test.
Now here is the Keras code for the network itself:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

#Set the params of the Neural Network
batch_size = 64
num_of_epochs = 40
hidden_layer_size = 256

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(hidden_layer_size, input_shape=(8, )))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(hidden_layer_size))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(hidden_layer_size))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', # using the mean squared error function
              optimizer='adam', # using the Adam optimiser
              metrics=['mae', 'mse']) # reporting the accuracy with mean absolute error and mean squared error

model.fit(X_train, y_train, # Train the model using the training set...
          batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_of_epochs,
          verbose=0, validation_split=0.1)

# All predictions in one array
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Questions:

1. **predictions** array will have all the values in the scaled format (between 0 and 1), but obviously I would need the predictions to be in their real values. How can I rescale those outputs back to the real values?
2. Is Min-Max or Z-Score standardization more appropriate for regression problems? What about this 'Batch-Normalization'?

Thank you,

Comment: You question is a bit too broad: it contains 2 questions, and the first one (rescaling) has nothing to do with keras.

Comment: Your first question has been answered and 2nd is out of scope for stackoverflow. Please check on https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), the `MinMaxScaler` class has an `inverse_transform` method which does what you want:

inverse_transform(X):   Undo the scaling of X according to feature_range.

Comment: Hi Camilleri, just one question. In my case I’m scaling the input data between -1,1 but at the output of the model.predict() the data range is not not between -1 and 1. I have some strange values like -1.00688391 any idea why?I think that when I rescale back with inverse_transofrm() this is causing bad results

Comment: @mik1904 what it the non linearity in your final layer? For the output to be in [0, 1] it should be a sigmoid, so in your case the formula can be 2 * sigmoid - 1. This should force results to be between -1 and 1

Comment: What's your question? I have an LSTM with one hidden layer activation function linear

Comment: @mik1904 If you don't use a special function as last linearity to constraint the range of your output values, there's no reason you wouldn't get something outside of -1, 1

Comment: so with linear activation functions there should be not problem right?

Comment: There will be a problem because they can take any value. I suggest you ask a new question (eventually quoting this one).

Answer (score 1):

For 1.: Use `inverse_transform()` with the same MinMaxScaler that you have fit_transformed your original data:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform

Comment: But the MAE/MSE reported by the model during training will still be using the "wrong" scale. Is there no way to do the inverse-scaling inside the model itself?

Comment: @HansBouwmeester You can use a [Lambda layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) to do the inverse scaling right after the last layer. You'd have to implement it on `tf.Tensor`s so you probably can't use `MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform` directly but it's very straightforward to write an inverse transform by hand.