# How to inverse_transform Keras evaluate function

Tags: python, keras

I have a training model with scaled features and targets and I want to get the evaluation results in the original scale. I am using Keras evaluate function `model.evaluate`. I tried with `inverse_transform` but got error saying `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`. How can I get the evaluation results in their original scale?

For scaling I used:

```
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
sc.fit(xtrain)
xtrain_sca = sc.transform(xtrain)
xtest_sca = sc.transform(xtest)
ytrain_sca = sc.fit_transform(ytrain)
ytest_sca = sc.transform(ytest)
```

I trained with:

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
hist = model.fit(xtrain_sca, ytrain_sca, epochs=200, batch_size=40, verbose=1)
```

and to evaluate using:

```
# Evaluate the model on the test data using `evaluate`
print('\n# Evaluate on test data')
results = model.evaluate(xtest_sca, ytest_sca, batch_size=40)
results = sc.inverse_transform(results)
print('test mse:', results)
```

Comment: Could you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: Can you show relevant parts of your source ?

Comment: Just some suggestions.. this is not an answer but a comment, 1) have you checked "results" is indeed a 2d array and not an 1d array ? You are calling "evaluate" to get it, are you sure that is the right method to get the object for the  inverse step ? And 2) You normalize... I found that MinMaxScaler has its own inverse function, see a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845627/re-scaling-outputs-from-a-keras-model-back-to-original-scale